# Signature not working in Custom ListView

Tags: android, digital-signature, gesture

I know for all of you this is a stupid question but it is not something like that.

In my custom listView there is one hidden layout which will be visible when click to button from my listView as a drop down. In that layout i have a one linear layout in which i want to draw signature. For that i have used `GestureOverLayView` and custom `Signture` class. But none of them working means signature is not drawing properly. Its just cuts when i tried to draw a signature. To overcome with this i have used

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

also

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Also tried to disable `InterceptTouchEvent` for `ListView`[image] on touch of it but none of them are working. So please anyone had faced similar issue before this? 
Help in advance would be appreciated !!

Comment: Is `GestureOverLayView` working outside of ListView? I mean empty activity containing `GestureOverLayView` only?

Comment: Yes it is working out side properly

Comment: I think problem is due to `ScrollView` inside of `ListView`.

Comment: I have tried to disable that too but it is not working too.

Comment: "Its just cuts when i tried to draw a signature". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: It means when i trying to draw only some of part is drawing

Comment: For signature which component you are using?

Comment: I too had the same issue are you using View for signature

Comment: Yes I am using View for signature.. Is your issue same with ListView? @Syed

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem

If you are using View for signature then in **onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)**
of view you have write this code **Activity.ListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)**.

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    Activity.ListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

   *Rest of code here*
    return true;
}

Because View will gets confused it's a signature draw or ListView scroll.
This should work